# Java ee api gets 404 on payara production server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, docker, docker-compose, payara

I'm running a java ee application on payara server with docker-compose, the application seems to work normally locally. But when deployed it will give a 404 on all "/api" requests. The jsp files seem to work fine.

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class SimulationApplication extends Application {
}
```

Is there something that could cause this behaviour.
I already tried restarting the server and docker. And the server logs don't show anything special. The only exception that it throws is that it can't backup the domain.xml to domain.xml.bak. I have tried to start it without the domain.xml mapped but this won't fix the api.

Docker-compose

```
version: "2"
services:

  java_ee:
    container_name: 'java'
    image: payara/server-full
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '4848:4848'
    links:
      - 'db:db'
    volumes:
      - './payara/autodeploy:/opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy'
      - './payara/lib:/opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib'
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xmx12g -Xms12g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

  angular:
    container_name: 'angular'
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - './angular:/usr/share/nginx/html'

  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: 'mysql'
    command: mysqld --user=root --verbose
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "Db"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pass"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
```

I didn't know for sure if this would be better suited for serverfault, if that fits better i'll post it there.

Comment: Okey, if i remember correctly (because this was a while back) the maven didn't compile right causing a very small compile that didn't actually have any code in it. When compiled on another machine it worked. So if you have this problem check the file size on compiled application. That being said, this was a long time ago and i have no idea how to actually fix it.